# Access - asking for non-existent parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have database where I have a Query3 when I add "GROUP BY" into SQL below, access wants a parameter, but I don't know why.

`SELECT Users.UserID
    FROM ((Users LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.ForUser=Users.UserID) LEFT JOIN OrdersContent ON     OrdersContent.ForOrder=Orders.OrderID) GROUP BY Users.UserID;`

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try to repair your database

Comment: Most likely you have mistyped one of the Table field names. Best regards,

Comment: Just a comment, why are you doing a GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? A simple SELECT DISTINCT is what you really are doing...

Answer (score 0):

Check your query properties, especially `order by`.